# EBS passes only GUEST user info to ADF Forms

Tags: oracle-adf

I have a trouble in passing current session info from EBS R12 to a custom build ADF Application. ADF forms are called form Functions defined in responsibility menu in EBS. 
I have done the setting explained in [ADF integration with EBS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43607686/adf-integration-with-ebs/44457156#44457156)  but only GUEST user info is passed to ADF instead of current user info. I mean regardless of the user logged in, system passes GUEST user info with user_id=6.

Can anyone advise me about the issue?

Thanks in advance
Elaheh

Answer (score 0):

I will Suggest you to use REST Webservices to call ADF Forms, and pass all the details in POST. Use ADF Taskflow and get all the required values from Webservice and pass to ADF forms. This way all the EBS Users can access the ADF forms.

Because the issue is that User Info object is generally generated by Oracle token.